# Can responsive SVG reposition element without scaling them?

Tags: css, svg, responsive

Giving this simple SVG :

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Normal size :</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 40" width="60" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="10" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="10" cy="30" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="30" r="5"/>
</svg>
```

What I want to do, and I'm not sure SVG can do it, is that if with css I make my svg 3 times larger (60px => 180px), it will take the whole space BUT not doing a simple scale/zoom like effet tha happens when preserving aspect ratio. I need to keep my circles with 5px radius, and just increasing the space between them.

To go from this [image] to this [image]

Comment: Do **not** define a `viewBox`, and set cx/cy to percentage values.

Comment: Will this work for `path` also ?

Comment: Not directly, path `d` commands need dimensionless coordinates in userspace coordinates. But if you use the CSS syntax for `transform`, you can use units and the `calc()` function like this: `style="transform:translate(calc(100% - 20px), 5%)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @ccprog: the primitives `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<ellipse>` and `<line>` support percentage values.

Apply `padding` to the parent svg to set fixed x an y offsets (eg. 10px/svg user units).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

svg {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.svg2 {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>resize me :</p>
<div class="resize">
  <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="0" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="30" r="5" />

    <circle cx="50%" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="50%" cy="30" r="5" />

    <circle cx="100%" cy="10" r="5" />
    <circle cx="100%" cy="30" r="5" />
  </svg>

</div>

<div class="resize">
  <svg class="svg2" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- align path center to x/y =0 by adding viewBox offset width/2 height/2 -->
    <symbol class="icon icon-home" id="iconHome" viewBox="20 20 40 40" overflow="visible">
        <path d="M36.4 22.2l-5.2 0l0 13l-3.4 0l0-16.7l-7.7-8.7l-7.7 8.7l0 16.7l-3.4 0l0-13l-5.2 0l16.4-17.4z"></path>
     </symbol>

    <use x="0" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="0" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    
    <use x="50%" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="50%" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    
    <use x="100%" y="0%"  href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
    <use x="100%" y="100%" href="#iconHome" width="20" height="20" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can also apply percentage values for `<path>` elements by wrapping paths in a `<symbol>` element (2nd example).

Comment: Thanks for the example with symbol it looks perfect for my needs !